# Show app above the lockscreen (i.e. Google Maps)

Tags: applications, lock-screens

i have a pattern lockscreen enabled. Now i have an app which plays audio files, but if you want to skip or pause the track, you have to unlock your phone.

So i want that my desired app is above the **lockscreen** and when i hit return or something else, than it shows me the lockscreen.
You can do this for example in Google Maps.

Is that possible?

**Device: N4, Lollipop 5.1, Root, Tasker installed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There might be a better solution out there, but for now this might help.*

---

You can use screen pinning option.

**Instructions to pin an app on the screen:**

1. Go to Settings →Security→Screen pinning
2. Enable screen pinning and also the option "Ask for unlock pattern before unpinning"
3. Now open the app you want, then switch over to the overview menu
4. Tap on the pin icon on the app.

You are good to go!

---

To get out from pinned screen, hold Back and overview button at the same time.

By doing this you get to interact with the app without unlocking the screen, and also as an additional benefit the unpinning gesture helps you from accidentally exiting from the app!

Comment: Thank you very much, i knew this option, but i never thought i can use it in this case. Works great. In the meantime i did this with tasker: If the desired app is opened AND headset plugged in, don't show the lockscreen.